# Manually Decrypt Partially Cloned APFS Volume

Tags: hard-drive, encryption, filevault, apfs

I recently attempted to clone a failing external drive to a new external drive. The clone failed part-way into the process. The original drive hardware has now fully failed, so I'm trying to recover as much as I can from the clone.

When I plug in the clone, macOS gives me an error reading "The disk 'Volume_Name' can't be unlocked. A problem was detected with the disk that prevents it from being unlocked." Disk Utility shows 1.6 TB used. I tried unlocking it from the command line and the Terminal output was `Passphrase incorrect or user does not exist`. I am certain I'm entering the passphrase correctly.

A scan in Data Rescue shows a recognizable list of files and folders. I can copy a file from the clone, but I can't open it. I am guessing that the files are encrypted individually while the folder structure is not.

From my research, macOS creates a separate cryptouser on an encrypted disk (separate from a Mac account/user) so that one password can open the disk on any Mac. When I used `diskutil apfs listcryptousers /dev/Volume_Name` in Terminal, the output is `No cryptographic users for Volume_Name` when it *should* output something like this:

[image: Terminal output]

I believe I've recovered the clone volume's cryptouser string from Keychain Access on two separate Macs (they match), so I have both the user and the passphrase. Is there a way to enter these manually and decrypt the drive? Either via the Terminal or a third-party piece of software?

For reference, I got a lot of information from [this page](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2019/01/15/unlock-or-decrypt-your-filevault-encrypted-boot-drive-from-the-command-line-on-macos-mojave/) even though it outlines boot drives instead of external ones.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This particular issue might be unrelated to potential corruption and instead due to different logical/physical sector sizes on the source and destination. If you can create loop devices with a custom sector size, try 4096 and 512. Otherwise, try copying the clone to a hard drive with the same sector size as the source drive.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).